# FreeBSD kill(2) implementation

Tags: system, freebsd, kernel, system-calls

I'm taking a FreeBSD course and am reading the implementation of system call kill(2).

http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_sig.c?v=FREEBSD82#L1687

Part of the code:

```
 1717         switch (uap->pid) {
 1718         case -1:                /* broadcast signal */
 1719                 return (killpg1(td, uap->signum, 0, 1, &ksi));
 1720         case 0:                 /* signal own process group */
 1721                 return (killpg1(td, uap->signum, 0, 0, &ksi));
 1722         default:                /* negative explicit process group */
 1723                 return (killpg1(td, uap->signum, -uap->pid, 0, &ksi));
 1724         }
 1725         /* NOTREACHED */
 1726 }
```

1) Is the pid manually set to 0 and -1 to indicate a process group or sth when calling the system call?

2) why does "signum" get involved?

3) how to understand the code that kills a single process? What does the code do?

I might be asking very stupid questions but please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) Is the pid manually set to 0 and -1
>   to indicate a process group or sth
>   when calling the system call?

- If the pid is 0 the signal is sent to
  all the processes in the same process
  group as the sender.
- If the pid is -1 the signal is sent
  to everyone (including the sender).
  The sender must have privileges to do
  this.

> 2) why does "signum" get involved?

- `signum` is the signal sent. There
  are lots of signals that do different
  stuff; try `kill -l`.

> 3) how to understand the code that
>   kills a single process? What does the
>   code do?

First the process is searched and `ESRCH` is returned if it can't be found (for example if you try to send a signal to some nonexistent pid).

```
if ((p = pfind(uap->pid)) == NULL) {
    if ((p = zpfind(uap->pid)) == NULL)
    return (ESRCH);
}
```

It is checked to see if we are allowed to signal it (with that signal):

```
error = p_cansignal(td, p, uap->signum);
```

If we *are* allowed to signal it, [`pksignal (tdsignal)`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_sig.c?v=FREEBSD82;im=10#L2009) is sent.

```
if (error == 0 && uap->signum)
    pksignal(p, uap->signum, &ksi);
```

Now we need to return from the function so we should drop locks

```
PROC_UNLOCK(p);
    return (error);
```

> I might be asking very stupid
>   questions but please help.

The kernel code is pretty obvious (no fancy algorithms are used). The only problem is that it's very large and you need patience.